# I want my terminal to "watch" all my .styl files and compile it to write a new CSS stylesheet out in the CSS folder

Tags: file, terminal, watch

I have one folder called "stylus" and in this folder i have a "stylus" and "CSS" folder, so i want to use this code: "stylus --watch ./stylus/ --out ./css" to watch all my .styl files in the stylus folder and compile itt and write a new .css stylesheet out in the css folder. 
But i get a message "command not found". Any idea how i can make this work?

Comment: What platform are you using? Is it Windows or mac?

Comment: I am using mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use npm packages(like `stylus`) on the terminal they have to be installed globally. The following command can be used to install the package globally:

`npm install stylus -g`

You may need `sudo` or run the terminal in `Administrator mode` to successfully run the above command.

After installing the package globally the global node_modules directory has to be added to the path. This can be achieved by executing the following command:

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:$(npm root -g)" >> ~/.bash_profile && . ~/.bash_profile
```

and then running the `stylus` again in your project.

The command below can be used to execute `stylus` without installing it:

```
npx stylus --watch ./stylus/ --out ./css
```